# Why does std::map not have a const accessor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, language-design, const-correctness

The declaration for the [] operator on a std::map is this:

```
T& operator[] ( const key_type& x );
```

Is there a reason it isn't this?

```
T& operator[] ( const key_type& x );
const T& operator[] const ( const key_type& x );
```

Because that would be incredibly useful any time you need to access a member map in a const method.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`operator[]` in a map returns the value at the specified key **or** creates a new value-initialized element for that key if it's not already present, so it would be impossible.

If `operator[]` would have a `const` overload, adding the element wouldn't work.

That answers the question. Alternatives:

For **C++03** - you can use iterators (these are `const` and non-`const` coupled with `find`). In **C++11** you can use the `at` method.

Answer (score 87):

As of C++11 there is `std::map::at` which offers const and non-const access.

In contrast to `operator[]` it will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception if the element is not in the map.

Comment: _that's_ a great addition.

Comment: That's much better than writing foo.get(bar)->second, thanks! =)

Comment: @Calder foo.find(bar)->second (not 'get') is just broken, unless you already know foo has an entry with bar as key, since otherwise it returns a non-dereferenceable iterator...

Answer (score 16):

These answers are correct in that `operator[]` has semantics to add a key if it doesn't exist, but I'd like to add another perspective:

Notice how `operator[]` returns a `T&`. That is, it returns a reference to the `value` that is associated with `key`. But what if there is no `key` in the `map`? What should we return? There's no such thing as a "null-reference," and throwing an exception would be annoying.

This would be one good reason for no `operator[] const`. What would you return to the user if you couldn't add anything to the `map` (because the operator is `const`), but they are looking for an item that doesn't exist? A good solution to this problem is to not have the `operator[] const`.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe std::map could have a const accessor if it would return an iterator instead of T&. But I guess that's what std::map::find() is for. It would also be bad performance-wise and not very intuitive.

Comment: Why not just have a `T null_` member in the map object and return const references to that?

Comment: @Inverse: And how do you initialize `null_`? What if, for example, `T` is `int`?

Answer (score 6):

The (non-`const`) `operator[]` creates the key if it doesn't exist.

The `const` version of that operator, if it existed, would have to have different semantics, since it wouldn't be able to add a new key.

I am sure you would agree that having `const` and non-`const` overloads with significantly different semantics would be a can of worms. Therefore no `const` version is provided.

There is a const `find()` member though, so you can use that in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Because the semantics of `operator[]` are to add the key if it doesn't exist.