# Compiler error when attempting to access std::map element with operator[]

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary, compiler-errors, typedef

I am trying to access elements of a map data structure by key, but am getting a compiler error. I have defined my map data structure using typedefs to simplify the syntax for map instantiation. As you can see, the key is of type `string` and the data are custom `GameComponent` objects:

```
typedef map<string, GameComponent*> ComponentMap;
typedef map<string, GameComponent*>::iterator ComponentMapIter;
typedef map<string, GameComponent*>::const_iterator ComponentMapCIter;
```

In a derived class of `GameComponent`, I am creating standard Composite pattern methods along with accessors for each unique GameComponent object stored in my map. However, using the array subscript operator to access objects in accessors results in the compiler error:

```
void Character::add(const string& key, GameComponent* comp)
{
    m_components->insert( make_pair(key, comp) );
}

void Character::remove(const string& key)
{
    m_components->erase(key);
}

Armor* Character::getArmor() const
{
    // ERROR:
    return static_cast<Armor*>(m_components["Armor"]);
}

Weapon* Character::getWeapon() const
{
    // ERROR:
    return static_cast<Weapon*>(m_components["Weapon"]);
}

Attributes* Character::getAttributes() const
{
    // ERROR:
    return static_cast<Attributes*>(m_components["Attributes"]);
}
```

The output of the compiler error shows an "invalid type" error, which has me scratching my head:

```
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp: In member function 'Armor* Character::getArmor() const':
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp:66: error: invalid types 'ComponentMap* const[const char [6]]' for array subscript
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp: In member function 'Weapon* Character::getWeapon() const':
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp:71: error: invalid types 'ComponentMap* const[const char [7]]' for array subscript
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp: In member function 'Attributes* Character::getAttributes() const':
/Users/Dylan/Desktop/RPG/character.cpp:76: error: invalid types 'ComponentMap* const[const char [11]]' for array subscript
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `m_components` is of type `ComponentMap*`.
When you write `m_components["Armor"]` compiler interprets that as an access to `"Armor"`-th element of dynamic array of `ComponentMap`s, which does not make any sense.

What you want is `(*m_components)["some string"]`. This will invoke `operator[]` of `ComponentMap`, but as Luchian Grigore and Olaf Dietsche mention, `std::map::operator[]` does not have a const overload, so this will fail too. The only option left is to use `find`.

The simplified edition will be:

```
Armor* Character::getArmor() const
{
    return static_cast<Armor*>(m_components->find("Armor")->second);
}

Weapon* Character::getWeapon() const
{
    return static_cast<Weapon*>(m_components->find("Weapon")->second);
}

Attributes* Character::getAttributes() const
{
    return static_cast<Attributes*>(m_components->find("Attributes")->second);
}
```

This code does not have the same behaviour as your original example and will fail if `m_components` does not have `"Armor"`, `"Weapon"` and `"Attributes"` elements.
The closest we can get is to explicitly handle absence of element and return `0` or `nullptr` if you use C++11.

Final correct C++03 compatible edition:

```
Armor* Character::getArmor() const
{
    ComponentMapCIter i = m_components->find("Armor");
    if (i != m_components->end())
        return static_cast<Armor*>(i->second);
    return 0;
}

Weapon* Character::getWeapon() const
{
    ComponentMapCIter i = m_components->find("Weapon");
    if (i != m_components->end())
        return static_cast<Weapon*>(i->second);
    return 0;
}

Attributes* Character::getAttributes() const
{
    ComponentMapCIter i = m_components->find("Attributes");
    if (i != m_components->end())
        return static_cast<Attributes*>(i->second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one I ended up using. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since `operator[]` in a `std::map` is not `const`, you can't use it inside `const` methods (on members, of course).

Use `at` (C++11) or `find` & iterators pre-C++11.

Related: [Why does std::map not have a const accessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902742/why-does-stdmap-not-have-a-const-accessor)

Answer (score 2):

`getArmor()`, `getWeapon()` and `getAttributes()` are defined `const`, but [`m_components[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)  might modify `m_components`. So you must either not define your methods `const` or use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) instead.

```
Armor* Character::getArmor() const
{
    auto i = m_components->find("Armor");
    if (i != m_components->end())
        return static_cast<Armor*>(i->second);

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Is `auto` a C++11 feature? It won't work using my version of the GNU compiler, which I think is pre-C++11...

Comment: @Dylan Just try it. It is already present with the `-std=c++0x` option. So if you have a reasonable current gcc (at least gcc 4.6), it will work.

Comment: @Dylan Just FYI, `auto` is already available with `gcc-4.4 -std=c++0x` (2009-04-21) and `nullptr` is available with `gcc-4.6 -std=c++0x` (2011-03-25).

Comment: Thanks, are these provided in specific header files?

Comment: @Dylan No header file is needed. When you add `-std=c++0x` to your command line (or `-std=c++11` in case of gcc 4.7), `auto` and/or `nullptr` are available.