# Throw exception when this instanced as const

Tags: c++, constants, instance

I've got an assignment operator in my class

```
template<typename T>
T&   array<T>::operator[](int value);
```

this method can be used like a const and none const method:

```
array[100] = value; // None const cause if size > array.size(): resize it!

std::cout << array[0]; // const
```

If my object is instanced as a const object and ask me to resize it I must throw an exception.

How can I know that I am instanced as a const object ?

Comment: That's not an assignment operator and `std::cout << array[0]` does not call the `const` overload.

Comment: nop but if I've got a
const array<int> b; 

std::cout << b[0]; does not work

Comment: What do you mean when you say "does not work" What happens, specifically? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: it does not compile cause my method is not const. But create 2 methods const/none const works! :)

Comment: @nsvir: So do that. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second version of your `[]` operator with a `const` modifier, it'll be called for const objects.

This one for non const objects:

```
template<typename T>
T& array<T>::operator[](int value);
```

And this one will be called for const objects:

```
template<typename T>
T& array<T>::operator[](int value) const;
```

That said don't forget that `const` in C++ is pretty weak and a simple `const_cast` will bypass it so you may think about another protection too.

**Edit:** note (see comments) that according to what you're doing you may declare return type of `const` function as `const T&`. It may be your case or not (if collection is `const` then its elements have to be const too?).

Comment: The return type of the `const` overload should be `const T&`.

Comment: @juanchopanza well, it may be but it depends on what OP is doing. A collection may be const but its elements non-const.

Comment: That would be a rather strange use of `const`, especially for a container which otherwise likes to pretend it owns the elements.

Comment: @delnan not really for how he's using that. Imagine array<int>, I'd feel "strange" to have a "const int" moreover I may feel natural to get Person from const array<Person> (note Person is non const). I think he needs that primary because he performs an array resize when assigning/reading from an out of range index.

Comment: @Adriano If you return a non-const reference, you allow things like `arr[i] = something;` and `arr[i].mutate_me();` and `arr[i]++;`. While it's technically possible to do this safely, it makes `const array<T>` much less useful (how often do you want to prevent resizing, but not changing elements?). The closest analogue to the behavior OP describes is `std::map`'s indexing, and of that there simply is [no `const` overload for `operator[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13902742/395760).

Comment: @delnan I'm not discussing about that (some people think A, someone else B, in general I would agree with you). Frankly an auto-sizing array is pretty confusing _per se_ but if you're using that I guess most of times you want to "freeze" it but you want still mutate its items (or you'll declare them as const too).

Comment: @Adriano AFAIK declaring the items const makes it impossible to use the vector in any way. You can't selectively cast between `array<T>` and `array<const T>` since templates are invariant, and you usually can't even instanciate `array<const T>` because `array<>` necessarily contains some lines assigning or otherwise modifying items.

Comment: @delnan sorry I didn't understand what you mean with last sentence in your commnet (...can't even...modifying items).

Comment: @Adriano Try `std::vector<const int>` for example. It doesn't work. Neither do most other containers.

Comment: @delnan ah OK, tnx I got what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Just provide a const version:

```
template<typename T>
const T&   array<T>::operator[](int value)const
{
  // throw exception
}
```

The `const` version will be called when your instance is constant, the non-const will be called when it's not constant.

Answer (score 0):

> this method can be used like a const and none const method:

You're wrong here. To use `[]` as a const method you should overload it with const definition of the method (`const {/*definition*/}`).

Additionally you should make your `int` argument (or `unsigned` the best) also a `const` variable.

That means declaring following headers:

```
template<typename T>
T&   array<T>::operator[](const int value);       // Read-write
template<typename T>
T&   array<T>::operator[](const int value) const; // Read
```

Comment: Well, even better would be a const size_t index!

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you don't want just to have const and non-const version of your operator, but what you want is to know if the value returned by the operator is modified or not, and if it is used in a context where it is not modified, exception should be thrown for out-of-range index. If so, I do not think it is possible in C++.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote? From the OP's code it is clear that different two versions of operator for the same non-const object (named 'array') are required.