# Why does the following not work when the map is const static

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following example:

```
enum class DOG_TYPE {SHEPHARD, COLLIE,UNKNOWN};

static  const std::map<std::string,DOG_TYPE> dogMap = {
                {"GS",DOG_TYPE::SHEPHARD}
};


DOG_TYPE getDogType(const std::string& dogtype) 
{
    if(dogMap.find(dogtype) != dogMap.end())
    {
        return  dogMap[dogtype];  -->Does not work when std::map is constant
    }
}

int main()
{
DOG_TYPE j = getDogType("GS");
std::cout << int(j);
}
```

In the above example the statement `return  dogMap[dogtype];` returns the error

```
error: passing 'const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, DOG_TYPE>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         return  dogMap[dogtype];
```

I would like to know why this happens and why cant map be `const static` ?

Comment: Related: [Why does std::map not have a const accessor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902742/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `operator[]` on a `std::map` creates the object if it doesn't exist. So it's an operation that can only be performed on a map you are allowed to modify. Use [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) instead.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `std::map` does not have an `operator[]` that is declared as `const`, so you can't use `operator[]` on a `const std::map` object.

`std::map::operator[]` is defined to return a *reference* to a keyed value. If the key is not found, **the map is modified** to insert a default value for the key so it can then bind the returned reference.  Obviously, modifying a `const std::map` cannot work, hence the compiler error.

To do what you are attempting, you can use `std::map::find()` to search for the key without inserting a new value for it. If the key is found, you can dereference the returned `iterator`.

Don't forget to have your function return a default value if the key is not found.

Try this:

```
DOG_TYPE getDogType(const std::string &dogtype) 
{
    auto iter = dogMap.find(dogtype);
    if (iter != dogMap.end())
        return iter->second;
    return DOG_TYPE::UNKNOWN;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by other, `operator[]` modify the map if the key isn't present.

But you can use `at()`

```
DOG_TYPE getDogType(const std::string& dogtype) 
{
    if(dogMap.find(dogtype) != dogMap.end())
    {
        return  dogMap.at(dogtype);
    }
}
```

And, if you can afford that `getDogType()` throws an exception when `dogtype` isn't a key in `dogMap`, simply

```
DOG_TYPE getDogType(const std::string& dogtype) 
{
        return  dogMap.at(dogtype);
}
```

p.s.: `at()` available only from C++11

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Using `find()` and `at()` together is redundant since you would be performing 2 identical searches to get 1 result. Use *either* `find()` *or* `at()`, not *both*.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - you're right: my first example is ineffective (and the second questionable because throw an exception when the OP could want `UNKNOWN` instead of an exception). As an excuse I say that my intention was only show to the OP that `operator[]` it's present only in non-const mode when `at()` is present (from C++11) with a const version.